# Get absolute file path of FileField of a model instance in Django

Tags: django, filepath, absolute-path, filefield

I have a page where people can upload files to my server.

I want to do something with the file in Celery. So, I need to know the absolute filepath of the uploaded FileFiled of my Model.

Let's say I queried the model and got the instance.
Now I need to get the absolute file path including the filepath.

`obj = Audio.objects.get(pk=1)`

I'm currently trying `obj.filename` and it's only printing the file name and not the absolute path.

I know I can get the upload path I input into `upload_to` and media directory, but I was wondering if there was a more DRY and automatic approach.

How do I get the `absolute path` of `file` which is a file filed in `obj`?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Found an answer.

I gotta do a `.path` on the `FileField`

If I do

```
obj.audio_file.path
```

`obj` is the model instance I queried and `audio_file` is the filefield

Comment: Can you provide official documentation link?

Comment: @decadenza, check `deconstruct` method for FileField class here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/_modules/django/db/models/fields/files/#FileField

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/files/#using-files-in-models